# Load Testing Database with JMETER : force re open connection to load test queries with connection opening

Tags: mysql, postgresql, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I need to validate a workload on a DB used to answer to http api.
In this context, on production, there are a lot of connections opened / closed. For a connection, there are only 2 or 3 small queries launched..   So connection 'activity' (open/close) has to be taken into account in our application.

I need to 'bench' / test the DB without the application stack,   so **I'd like JMETER to query directly the database like the web service would do..**

When using / configuring odbc connection pool through "jdbc connection configuration",  I only see the way to define a large pool of connection that will be used, after, to launch queries.  That mean...  the connections stay alive after playing ThreadGroup scenario, and are reused.    In real application, for a scenario,  this would make a new connection, and would close this one at the end.

**Is there a way to do it (make a new connection for every ThreadGroup run) in JMETER with JDBC 'components' ?**

as a workarround, I created a small script and asked jmeter to run it... but it's far more heavier for the server to do it (launch a new process each time to execute the (php) script..  and I couldn't load the server enough by doing it, to reproduce the workload.

[image: Screen shot of the jdbc connection pool]

Answer (score 0):

JMeter [is actually calling Connection.close() function](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/src/protocol/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jdbc/sampler/JDBCSampler.java#L100) after executing the statement, under the hood the connection is being returned to the [pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) and it waits for the next thread which requires the connection.

If your application behaviour is the same you don't need to worry about anything. If it's different - you won't get such precise control with the [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler.

If you want to create and destroy connections manually you will have to switch to [JSR232 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and implement connection and query logic in [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), see [Working with a relational database](https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html) Groovy user manual chapter for more details, code examples, etc.